# export requirejs application as a module for use in third party require application

Tags: javascript, build, requirejs, gruntjs

I have require module, with dependancies.

```
define(['dep1','dep2'],function(Dep1, Dep2){

    var MyModule;
    MyModule.prototype.init = function(){
      //my module logic
    }
    return MyModule;
})
```

I need want to use R.JS optimiser to bring in all dependancies, including shims, into a single file that can be subsequently used as a module in a third party requirejs app.

```
require(['myCompiledModule'], function(MyModule) {
  var module = new MyModule();
  module.init();
});
```

Can the optimizer be used in such a way as to be left with a require module in this way?

Currently, I am using the following options in my Gruntfi

```
options: {
    baseUrl: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
    mainConfigFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/myModule.js',
    optimize: 'none',
    paths: {
        'myPaths': '../bower_components/some/deps'
    },
    name: 'MyModule',
    out: 'test-harness/guides/assets/myCompiledModule.js'
}
```

But when I import the module into a third party application, I get an empty function.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to do exactly the same.